# How to display a dialog box when the app is closed

Tags: java, android, modal-dialog

so ... I created a backdoor in original apk but I was wondering if there is a way to display a confirmation box, and when the user confirms I want to install another apk, how can I do this using metasploit?
**And if there is no way to do it using metasploit then I will have to create this dialog and include it in my app, and then how will I display this when the app is closed?**
Someone gives me a guide of what to look for if i know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Push message(FCM) for this case